# Error: cannot find symbol variable GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES + OpenCV on Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-studio-2.3

I am beginner in developing Opencv application on Android. I have two error in compiling an OpenCV sample (15 puzzle) on Android:
1. **error: cannot find symbol variable GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES**
2. **error: package android.hardward.camera2 does not exist**.

Answer (score 21):

Change the compile SDK version and build tools to latest **BUT on module opencv** in Project Structure.

[image: configuration project structure]

Answer (score 3):

Change the compile SDK Version and Build tools( 21 or latest)
I'm using Version 25

app/Open Module settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1O5.jpg